# What was the reason Jesus allowed Christians to eat pork?

Tags: christianity, middle-east, food

Pork prohibitions date back to ancient Mesopotamia where for some cults consumption of pork was banned.

Many people speculate if the bans against pork was to protect against trichinosis, which turns out to be almost definitely untrue.

> "there's no evidence the parasite existed in ancient Palestine, and other meats could be equally dangerous"

Many historians believe that pigs eventually were perceived as dirty because of their habits to eat carrion and feces, not unlike dogs or chicken however…

So if pigs share the same behaviour as other animals why were they singled out and deemed unclean?

This practice was kept for what became 'the Jews' for a very long time, until Jesus out of nowhere declared "all foods clean" which meant he went against the established norm.

Were there any significant historical events that triggered Jesus to end this long tradition, or was it just a coincidence?

Comment: this question would be improved it if [sourced quotations](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/633/edit) and provided citations for [prior research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote?lastactivity).  All questions should, at a minimum, explain why the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_restrictions_on_the_consumption_of_pork) page doesn't answer the question.  Question would also be significantly stronger if it  were _one_ question, rather than two.

Comment: [Matthew 5:17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_5:17)  and [Matthew 5:18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_5:18) don't agree with you.

Comment: I'll add an Historical answer, but I should add that if you're the kind of person who wants to see only answers that don't contradict a set of supernatural beliefs you like to hold, perhaps this isn't the site for you, and one of the religious sites would be less stressful. (eg: Christianity or Biblical Hermunatics)

Comment: "... where the consumption of pork "suddenly" got banned in the year 2.400 B.C." I'd like to see something to back that up.

Comment: Given @T.E.D.'s answer shouldn't this be two separate questions - the origin in 2400BCE with references for that and then the Christian chnage

Comment: @Jos - Got curious about that myself. Found a reference online saying that and attributing it to [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Prehistory-Humankinds-Casebooks-Criticism/dp/019516928X/ref=as_li_ss_tl?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1499718260&sr=1-1&keywords=Patterns+in+Prehistory&linkCode=ll1&tag=humanpast-20&linkId=5acaedf80a6b7bd8fd8bfb2b8531f05d) . I'd still like to see exactly what that book said about it (and perhaps its references), because this was new to me. Added links to both sources to the Q

Comment: @T.E.D. The problem here is that the book you linked is 1: converted to a link I cannot access (spammy proxy prohibition–rads/AMZN) 2: "Patterns in Prehistory" discusses the in your A ominous "reasons", quite well, but says nothing about the sudden religious banning (p238 seems to come closest? But neither Sumerian prohibition nor 2400 BCE (nor 2700) I could locate in it)? — We need QOP to provide his ref here with a quote (& humanpast seems to have glitched there?!

Comment: @LаngLаngС - Converted the book link to a Goodreads link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question appears to be largely plagiarized from an uncited source.

Answer (score 18):

#### Jews and Pigs

We don't really know.

The problem with this one is that lots of people have [plausible-sounding reasons for the prohibition](https://medium.com/belover/why-do-jews-not-eat-pork-6eabfb241c36). Lots of people have *implausible*-sounding reasons for this too. Beyond, "because the Torah says so", none of them are really provable, or have any kind of serious historical consensus. Even within the Torah, [Genesis 9:3](https://biblehub.com/genesis/9-3.htm) implies its just fine to eat them, so it isn't consistent with itself on the subject.

> Every moving thing that lives shall be food for you; and just as I gave you the green plants, I give you everything.

(NRSV)

It should be noted that [Deuteronomy 14:8](https://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/14-8.htm), which explicitly forbids eating pig meat, is today considered by textual analysts to have been authored from a different source than the Genesis passage above. However, [The Deuteronomist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuteronomist) is likely an older source than [The Priestly Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_source) responsible for that bit of Genesis (by a couple of centuries), and there's little indication that pork consumption was briefly acceptable during that time.

---

#### Mark 7:19

Mark was written down most likely [sometime around 66–74 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Mark#Authorship,_date_and_genre). While that's more than a generation after the death of Jesus, it would still make it the oldest Gospel (so in some ways our best historical source for Jesus).

This was right around the time of the [destruction of the second temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War). Prior to then there was a faction of the new sect that believed in keeping it a Jewish-only religion. This faction was [led by figures such as James and Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James,_brother_of_Jesus#The_Jerusalem_Church) and was headquartered in Jerusalem. Another faction believed in opening the new faith up to the world ('Gentiles'), and was led by many missionaries throughout the Roman world, most famously Paul.

It was this latter faction that wrote Paul's original epistles, and then later Mark. This faction clearly had a vested interest in converting Gentiles, so you find a lot of things in their writings that are convenient for that. Specifically the removal of the requirements for Jewish conversion (and particularly circumcision!), and not needing to follow the strict Jewish cleanliness and dietary restrictions. This is almost certainly why you find that passage in Mark. Notice how the implication is then helpfully spelled out explicitly. That very rarely happens in the Gospels. Whoever wrote that didn't want any argument whatsoever on the matter. Paul's epistles (which remember were written *earlier* than Mark) indeed do hint that there was a great deal of argument on this issue in the early Church. What better way to end the argument, than to put it in Jesus' mouth?

About the time Mark was being written, the Romans got entirely fed up with the constant Jewish rebellions and occasional destruction of Roman legions. Rome laid siege to Jerusalem, [burned it to the ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War), and killed or enslaved and deported everyone living there. This also had the effect of decapitating (if not completely wiping out) the "Jewish-only" Christian faction. If they had their own gospels putting other words in Jesus' mouth, they burned with the city.

So basically what happened is that this pro-Gentile passage was useful to have for one of the two early Christian factions, and Gentiles (Romans) ended up long-term being the right horse to bet on. So that one early Gospel survived to this day.

The Gospel of Matthew however, appears to have come later from a Jewish Christian community that survived the destruction of the second temple. It was much more concerned with [preserving the Jewish nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Matthew#Relationship_with_the_Jews) of the religion, and to that end used Jesus' voice to directly contradict Mark on this matter in [5:17-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205&version=NIV).

> Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I
> have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. For truly I tell
> you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not
> the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law
> until everything is accomplished.

Comment: +1 - Don't understand the down votes, this strikes me as a pretty good tilt at the question.

Comment: @TheHonRose - At least 2 of those came quite early, when the answer only answered 1 of the two questions. I'm guessing that had something to do with it.

Comment: There was no "Jewish state" then, the better argument for dating the gospels lies with Marcion's 'proto-Luke' (although 'of course', now, Mark is still the more popular '1st', with Matt still with some supporters; late-dating is a thing).

Comment: I must give you -1 because although you wrote an extensive answer, you completely misunderstood Peter. He did not want to keep Christianity as Jews-only religion. He simply wanted to introduce Jewish customs to gentile (including avoiding pork, circumcision etc ...) . His "fraction" was defeated, that is true, but this has little to do with destruction of Jerusalem, as early Christians were persecuted by Judaist Jews, and were often forced to flee.

Comment: @rs.29 Some true in yours. The Peter-angle is even less clear-cut than you present it. At Antioch and in Galatians we see a Peter alleged by Paul to be flip-flopping on these issues. Last we hear from that very issue of 'eating' 'in bible' is 'Peter did give in to 'Judaizers''. So we have Paul's word on it contradicting TED (Peter being OK with all Paul did) _and_ corroborating TED: Peter siding against Paul on eating (& more stuff?). The 'parting of the ways' took quite a while longer & wasn't as radical in general as you seem to imply (from Paul to gospel-writing time, with Peter enigmatic)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС - I went and looked into it, and it looks like the modern version of that line of thinking is the [Four-document hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-document_hypothesis). However that generally these days drops the idea of a "proto-Luke" (or "L"). I kind of like the idea of an earlier lost source myself, but have to admit it doesn't seem necessary to the hypothesis.

Comment: Favouring the Schwegler/Klinghardt/Vinzent/Trobisch-line, it's well worth looking into the most recent arguments for/around https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Marcion Not without own problems, but certainly solving a lot more. // 70AD is a dating that firmly rests on 'Temple-kaputt', but that's _just one passage_ for which we might be quite convinced of 'post' (ex eventu), while the whole text _we have_ wasn't 'finished' then, surely. We desire a clear lineage for the synoptics, but my guess is we see quite a prolonged parallel intertextuality? (cf eg 10.1163/15700720-12301234)